# How to force build to fail if resource missing?

Tags: c#, build, resources

While working on a project with resource files in C# (.resx) a number of resource keys were modified.

While IntelliSense will show that a resource is missing, the project will compile normally.

My guess is that the system allows key lookup at runtime in resources, thus not failing. Is there a way to force build failure if such a resource is missing?

Comment: I guess making these resources embed will solve the problem, but I'm not sure, you should check.

Comment: Checked it, the resources are already embedded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160294/msbuild-force-compile-failure-on-missing-project-files

Comment: Could you do it using an inline task? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx